# lsearch does not match elements that require curly-braces (Tcl 8.4)

Tags: list, tcl, brackets, curly-braces

I'm dealing with a big number of signals. I've been able to store them into a list, but since their name have brackets the signals are store in a list. Latter on, using regexp, I analyze some output produced and, if there's a match, I needed to set a flag.

In this following example I show the element added to the list and, later one, I try to check if the same element is inside of the list using **lsearch**

```
set mylist [list]
set element {aux[1]}

lappend mylist $element
puts "mylist: $mylist \nelement: $element\n\[list element\]: [list $element]"
```

The result of this puts is:

```
mylist: {aux[1]}
element: aux[1]
[list element]: {aux[1]}
```

Since my element is stored as **{a[1]}**, I've not found a way to make **lsearch** to return a match

```
set result [lsearch $mylist $element]
set result2 [lsearch $mylist [list $element]]

puts $result
puts $result2
```

Both results return '-1'.

I've seen solutions, but none of them using Tcl 8.4; And I need to use it due to backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-exact` matching style. The default style is `-glob`, which means that the substring `[1]` matches a single `1`.

```
lsearch -exact $mylist $element
# => 0
```

Documentation: [lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm)

Comment: I was sure I tried that. 
Must've made a mistake in between. It works =), thanks!